# Can I drill a hole in PVC conduit body to run a coax cable?

Tags: wiring

I need to install a new grounding rod at my house and will be running the grounding conductor through an LB body and PVC conduit down to the ground.

But I also need to run a new coax cable into the house nearby, so I'm wondering whether I can drill a hole in the conduit body, install a feed-through bushing, and run the coax into the house through the same conduit? (I'd loop the coax and weather-seal it on the outside, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a cubic inch listing on the conduit body it may be possible.

You still have to meet the wire fill requirements the CGB or clamp, x multiplier for the largest wire size has to be added to the total count of wires cubic inch.

This is the same as modifying a  listed J Box.

Your AHJ may not allow but if it has a stamped volume code has nothing stopping it.

If it is not stamped then it is not allowed to splice or modify. (Conduit body’s don’t have a approved size chart like boxes do).

Outside a cgb (cord grip bushing) that seals / clamps the wire would be required. Inside standard 2 screw clamps are ok.